# Why there is no entry in HKU for user created by Salt

Tags: windows, registry, salt-stack, sid

I have a user created by Salt `user.present` state. Details returned by user.info:

```
----------
account_disabled:
    False
account_locked:
    False
active:
    True
comment:
description:
disallow_change_password:
    False
expiration_date:
    2106-02-07 07:28:15
expired:
    False
failed_logon_attempts:
    0
fullname:
    Student
gid:
groups:
    - Użytkownicy
home:
    Student
homedrive:
    C:
last_logon:
    2022-02-21 21:01:13
logonscript:
name:
    Student
passwd:
    None
password_changed:
    2022-02-21 21:01:07
password_never_expires:
    False
profile:
    Student
successful_logon_attempts:
    2
uid:
    S-1-5-21-3207633127-2685365797-3805984769-1043
```

My goal is to add some registry entries for the user. I tried using `reg.present` state to add a key with the follwing error:

```
      ID: HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3207633127-2685365797-3805984769-1043\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Uninstall!NoAddRemovePrograms
Function: reg.present
  Result: False
 Comment: Failed to add None to HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3207633127-2685365797-3805984769-1043\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Uninstall!NoAddRemovePrograms
 Started: 21:14:39.581549
Duration: 0.0 ms
 Changes:
```

When I run `reg.list_keys HKU`, I don't see the `S-1-5-21-3207633127-2685365797-3805984769-1043` listed above:

```
- .DEFAULT
- S-1-5-19
- S-1-5-20
- S-1-5-21-3207633127-2685365797-3805984769-1001
- S-1-5-21-3207633127-2685365797-3805984769-1001_Classes
- S-1-5-18
```

I have logged in as the user to make sure the profile is fully created. No HKU entry even then. Why is the entry not getting created?

BTW: I've verified using `regedit` if the info returned by Salt is correct and it is. I do not see the user id using `regedit` either.

Comment: To double-check, what is the SID returned by `whoami /user` when logged in as `Student`?

Comment: `whoami` returns just hostname\Student - it does not spit out the SID. `wmic useraccount` returns uid reported by Salt (S-1-5-21-3207633127-2685365797-3805984769-1043)

Comment: That's why I said `whoami /user`, not `whoami`

Comment: gotcha. I get hostname\student and S-1-5-21-3207633127-2685365797-3805984769-1043

Answer (score 1):

HKU is a pain to work with. and normally shouldn't be edited directly. so the only users that can show up there are logged in users.

I'm not sure why the user is not showing up when the user is logged in however. that sounds like a windows issue.

You can force load users into HKU see https://www.pdq.com/blog/modify-the-registry-of-another-user/